# Automating process of adding multiple combinations and different images for them

Tags: combinations, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

Is it possible to automate such process:

I have to add many products that have 2 attributes (size and color)
Each color (doesn't matter what size) have different set of photos.

I can easy generate size/color products. But then each of them I have to pick different photos. With 6 sizes and 10 colors its 60 combinations... and its only 1 product

Is there any way to do this in groups. For example:

```
Size: XL, X, S, M.....
Color: Black
Images: black_img1, black_img2, black_img3

Size: XL, X, S, M.....
Color: Red
Images: red_img1, red_img2, red_img3
```

Comment: Did u find the answer?

Comment: No I didn't. I resigned. Maybe some day someone will write such module. I must pick every colour by my own ;)